# Abstract classes in Python, is it wrong to add methods with and without implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that Java abstract classes may contain a mix of methods declared with or without an implementation.

**Can the same be said about python simulated abstract classes?**

The examples that I have gathered so far online is with no implementation.I am trying to maintain good coding habits with Python and would like to know the pythonic way.

Comment: Python does not have abstract classes. Are you referring to the use of the `abc` module to simulate them?

Comment: @chepner - Thanks for the correction, Python does not provide abstract classes. ABC provides the infrastructure to define an abstract class. Yes, I am referring to the ABC module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should note that abstract methods/classes aren't a core language feature in Python as they are in Java, though this behaviour can be simulated using `ABC` (abstract base class) and the `@abstractmethod` decorator.

However, similarly to Java, this approach is fine. Your non-abstract method(s) will be inherited from your superclass as normal and your abstract methods will require an explicit subclass implementation **only** if declared as abstract using the `@abstractmethod` decorator. Otherwise, Python won't complain that an "abstract" method isn't implemented in a subclass. It's worth looking at the [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) documentation which covers this.

Inherited non-abstract methods can *also* be overridden in subclasses if needed, providing a new implementation if some extra-specific logic is required further down in your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't have to implement an inherited abstract method if you don't intend to instantiate the class.

Comment: This is only true if there is some sort of enforcing mechanism being used, such as [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/abc.html). Otherwise, subclasses will happily inherit the un-implemented methods of its parent.

Comment: @b_c The discussion is about abstract classes, which by definition means something like `abc`; the language itself has no concept of abstract base classes.

Comment: @chepner I'd rather not assume that OP was referring to `abc` since it wasn't mentioned. I had a similar experience starting with Python where I thought it had built-in abstract enforcement, so I wanted to avoid potentially mis-leading information.

Comment: @b_c Good point, especially after re-reading the question. I've commented for the OP to clarify.

Comment: But given the nature of Python inheritance (which itself is predicated on run-time attribute lookup), I don't know that you could (or would want to) implemente any kind of compile-time enforcement of abstract method overriding.

Comment: @psilocybin Perfect! This is the type of answer I was looking for.